# JSF inputtext + Converter

Tags: jsf, converters

First, I show my code:

**XHTML page:**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="ffffffffff">
        <p:inputText value="#{prueba.dato}" >
            <p:ajax event="keyup" process="@this" />
        </p:inputText>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Prueba implements Serializable {

    private String dato = "ASSSS";

    public String getDato() {
       return dato;
    }

    public void setDato(String dato) {
        this.dato = dato;

        System.out.println("DAAAAAA: " + dato);
    }

    public void listener() {
        System.out.println("LISTENEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
    }
}
```

**Converter**

```
@FacesConverter
public class SnaCarreraConverter extends SelectItemsConverter {
    //CODE
}
```

My problem, **setDato** is always getting a **null** value. But when I modify the converter to this:

@FacesConverter(forClass=SnaCarrera.class)

adding forClass resolve my problem, I don't know why this happens. Is The inputText trying to find a Converter without add the converter property?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `SelectItemsConverter` is for `<f:selectItems>`. The `<p:inputText>` is not a `<f:selectItems>`. So the `SelectItemsConverter` is useless for the `<p:inputText>`. See also its documentation and showcase.

Second, it's normal to give the `Converter` implementation an ID or a "for-class" in order to use it. Otherwise you can't refer it in the `<x:inputSomething converter>` attribute, or in the `<f:converter>` tag, or you can't auto-associate it with a certain class. This requirement is totally unrelated to the `SelectItemsConverter`. It's just required by standard JSF spec.